# is the return value of fileperms function in php decimal or octal?

Tags: php

I've learned that the output of fileperms function in php must be an octal number but when I'm using it I'm getting a decimal number in output and I'm confused with that.

I created a directory using the mkdir function (so the default permissions should be 0777) but when I used the fileperms function to display permissions it returned 16895 which is not even an octal number, so I converted it to decimal and got 40777 which is really the true answer, so my question here is when does this function return octal value and does it return a decimal? or does it return decimal numbers all the time and I should convert it to octal using function like sprintf ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php#refsect1-function.fileperms-returnvalues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on PHP documentaion :

> Returns the file's permissions as a numeric mode. Lower bits of this mode are the same as the permissions expected by chmod(), however on most platforms the return value will also include information on the type of file given as filename. The examples below demonstrate how to test the return value for specific permissions and file types on POSIX systems, including Linux and macOS.

So if you use code like this, that will fix the problem :

```
<?php echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/mydirectory')), -4); ?>
```